# Help me find the title of a sci-fi apocalyptic movie following a brother-sister duo, but the sister is different somehow

Tags: story-identification, movie, young-adult, zombie-apocalypse

I need help finding the title of this movie I had to have watched sometime between 2009-2016 where the movie takes place in the middle of some kind of zombie apocalypse. The main characters are this brother and what I think is his little sister (?) but nonetheless a young girl who is traveling with him. I can’t remember anything too plot-specific, but there are two key scenes I remember from this film.

1. In the climax of the movie, their group is running from a horde of zombies and into some chamber which has a gate that will close between the MCs and the horde. In order to save her brother and their friends, the little girl stays back and fights off the zombie horde while the gate closes. Everyone thinks she dies but then the gate opens to find that she killed them all.
2. At the literal end of the movie when the brother is with his new girlfriend in their room, they are implied to start having sex and the camera pans up to the ceiling/vents where the little girl is watching them.

I also vaguely remember there being a scene where their group goes to an abandoned mall of some sort and they watch the remnants of some sort of news channel explaining that there has been an outbreak of some virus that is causing people to turn into these zombie-like monsters.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - The site already tells them that.

Comment: Was this live-action or animated?

Answer (score 71):

This is a fair description of the science fiction film [Serenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_(2005_film))

> Serenity is a 2005 American space Western film written and directed by
> Joss Whedon in his feature directorial debut. The film is a
> continuation of Whedon's short-lived 2002 Fox television series
> Firefly and stars the same cast, taking place after the events of the
> final episode. Set in 2517, Serenity is the story of the crew of
> Serenity, a "Firefly-class" spaceship. The captain and first mate are
> veterans of the Unification War, having fought on the losing
> Independent side against the Alliance. Their lives of smuggling and
> cargo-running are interrupted by a psychic passenger who harbors a
> dangerous secret.

Comment: And, assuming this is the right answer, this question is a dupe of [Movie about Space Pirates that have bodies tied to their ships](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187943/movie-about-space-pirates-that-have-bodies-tied-to-their-ships)

Comment: The roomful of dead reapers is definitely a strong connection.

Comment: There are a lot of details in this question that do not fit this movie. Would a viewer really remember an abandoned mall in a zombie apocalypse rather than crashing spaceships and swordfights?

Comment: @user3153372 The vaguely remembered "abandoned mall" scene does actually fit - without going into too many plot details, they visit a planet whose population has been wiped out, and see a video message from a researcher there which reveals the key plot twist.

Comment: I also have a bit of trouble thinking of River as "a little girl" in anything but that flashback scene in the school, but I'd be a tad disturbed if there were a movie with an actual little girl spying on sex from the rafters...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots While not a child physically, River is definitely portrayed as having a child-like mindset

Comment: If the name “Reavers” (when referring to the Zombies) sounds familiar to the OP , this is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: This. River Tam, a psychic, is rescued by brother Simon from an Alliance lab conducting neural stripping to turn her into a military weapon. (0:03:33). The Alliance try to find and kill her. The mall scene (1:12:20) and not-a-virus misinformation. Serenity crash lands into a tunnel(1:25:40), and crew retreat to a gated room to escape Reavers (Zombie like psychopathic killers). River kills them (1:41:30). Gate opens(1:42:07). Simon and gf (1:44:39). Camera does pan up to River clamped to ceiling and childhood but not here.

Comment: [Ceiling River is watching you have sex](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/79886-ceiling-cat)

Answer (score 0):

The Girl with all the Gifts?

The climactic ending sounds like the ending of that movie

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the story in question (i.e. what details match the ones given in the question).

Comment: ? "The film ends with a tearful Justineau, safe but confined to the sealed mobile lab due to the lethal spore-filled air. Outside, the hybrid children of the army base, along with the feral children, sit together, kept sternly in place by Melanie. Justineau speaks through a microphone, educating the newly-dominant human species"